# Can I use my USB Port for External Monitor?

Tags: usb, display, multiple-monitors, hdmi

I have a Dell G315 3579 laptop and I have already a monitor which is connected to my HDMI. I have another external monitor and I want to use it too but I don’t want to use HDMI hub. I want to use my USB port to use my new monitor. I will use a VGA to USB or DPI-D to USB cable to connect. I think my USB version is 3.0, how can I check it?

Comment: USB 3.0 doesn’t support what you want

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your laptop, the ***Dell G3 15 3579***, has a configuration that includes a **Thunderbolt 3** (port type is a USB Type-C, USB 3.1) port. If you have that port you might be able to use that (with an adapter) to output video to your 2nd external monitor).

Do you have this port?
[image]

If you have this, you can use a simple (and pretty affordable) USB Type-C to DisplayPort adapter.

If you do not have this port, and you want to use your **USB 3.1 Type A** ports for this, you'd need a USB Video Graphics Adapter (which is a bigger adapter and is way more expensive), something like [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004D0QC0A) or [this](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B004D0QC0A).

Comment: I don’t have this port. Also I don’t have USB Type-C

Comment: Then the 2nd method is the only way, an external USB graphics adapter. Note, this is not a simple adapter/cable, but a small GPU-like system running in it, therefor they are pricey, and important to take from a reputable brand.

Comment: Thanks, I hope this will solve my problem. Do you have any recommendations for this adapter? My limit is 35 Euro.

Comment: I linked 2 such options and they tend to be more like 40-50, but I can try to find something. Which country are you in, and which input types does your monitor have?

Comment: Germany, inputs are VGA - DVI-D.

Comment: Maybe this one https://www.amazon.de/-/en/DIGITUS-graphics-adapter-1920x1080-plastic-black/dp/B01MXQI31B?th=1

Comment: Thank you for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

From Dell's website for that model.

> Supports USB 3.1 Gen 2, DisplayPort 1.2, Thunderbolt 3 and also enables you to connect to an external display using a display adapter.
>
> NOTE: A USB Type-C to DisplayPort adapter (sold separately) is required to connect a DisplayPort device.

[Link to information from Dell](https://www.dell.com/support/manuals/en-us/g-series-15-3579-laptop/dell-g3-3579-setupandspecifications/left?guid=guid-12cd14bb-8db3-47d7-a090-15d75787517a)

Looks like you can use USB Type C to DisplayPort.

Comment: Answer can be improved.  Importantly:  Thunderbolt 3 (USB Type-C) port ***(Optional)***  If included then good to go.  If not, then `DisplayLink` only.

Comment: I don’t have DisplayPort, USB Type-C. I just have HDMI and USB ports. So what should I do?